# Problem with onChange for Masked Input in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, onchange, maskedinput

I am trying to create a masked input in React (without using a masked input library). My problem is that I could not access e.key using the onchange prop -- it just gives me undefined, so I used onKeyDown instead -- this is working, but I am getting a warning in the console that says :

"Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`."

I have tried using keyDown to get the key, and then masking the input using the onChange function, but it is always one character behind where it should be.

This is what my code looks like so far, I would be so appreciative of any tips, etc. that could fix this.

```
class App extends Component {
  state={
    input: "",
    acc: "", //this is an accumulator I'm using to hold the unmasked version of the input
    currentKey: ""
  }

  getKey = (e) => {
    if(e.key === "Backspace"){ //removes last letter on backspace
      const lastLetterRemoved = this.state.acc.substr(0,this.state.acc.length-1)
      this.setState({acc: lastLetterRemoved, input: this.mask(lastLetterRemoved)})
    } else {
      let currentChar;
      if(!Number(e.key)){//ignores non-numeric characters
          currentChar = ""
      } else {
        currentChar=e.key //adds current key to accumulator, masks it and sets input value
        const currentAcc = this.state.acc + currentChar
        this.setState({acc: currentAcc, input: this.mask(currentAcc)})
      }
    }
  }

//function to mask the input as the user types the Numbers should appear
//already formatted as an amount of currency
//example: inputting 123 would behave like this $0.01 ... $0.12 ... $1.23
  mask = (num) => {
    let dollars;
    let cents;
    if(num<10){
      dollars = "0"
      cents = `0${num}`
    } else {
      dollars=Math.floor(num/100)
      cents=num%100
    }
    return `$${dollars}.${cents}`
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <input 
          value={this.state.input || "$0.00"} //value is $0.00 to start, then it is whatever the input is
          onKeyDown={this.getKey}/>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Thank you in advance for any pointers!

Comment: How exactly is the input field supposed to work? I'm apparently not supposed to use arrow keys. I also can't enter `$1.20`

Comment: yes, sorry, I am still working on ironing out edge cases like zeroes and arrow keys, but it is supposed to add numbers to the end of the value and move the decimals as you go, so for example if you input 123, the input would read "$1.23" or if you input "12" it would read "$0.12" or if you input 12345 it would read "$123.45" etc

Comment: Here's my take: https://codesandbox.io/s/3rwywn57q I'm not going to post it as answer because I don't really like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a long conversation going on at a [related issue on React Github Repo](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1118). And there is no elegant solution provided yet.

The simplest solution at the moment to remove this warning is, addind a seperate dummy onChange prop (`onChange={() => {}}`) to the input element as suggested [in this post](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1118#issuecomment-225899499)

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. See “How does accepting an answer work?” meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/218666